# cygwin cannot exec 'git-add--interactive' permission denied

Tags: git, cygwin

I am using Cygwin on Windows 8. I've installed git version 2.1.4 through the Cygwin installer. When I run
    $ git add -i
I get a 
    fatal: cannot exec 'git-add--interactive': Permission denied

I've chmoded the file that I would like to add as well as the folder containing the file, and even /usr/libexec/git-core and git-add--interactive to 755. I've also chgrped the group from None to Users in both folder, as well both the file and git-add--interactive. It's really bugging me because I do not have the same problem on MsysGit. Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened for me too.  After lots of digging, I found that /bin/cygperll5_14.dll was missing.  Using cygwin's setup.exe, I **Reinstalled `perl` and `perl_base`**.  Then everything started working.

Isn't that obvious? ;-)

Comment: Thank you!  The packages names are `perl` and `perl_base` for anyone who, like me, was momentarily confused.

Answer (score 0):

Try `git add .` -- it will add all the files and subdirectories in current folder
Hope it works.

Comment: Thanks Amol, but I am actually able to add files. I get the permission error when I try to add the files interactively, using `git add -i` or `-p`. I'm not sure what permissions Cygwin is referring to.